# WPF Programatically change row background color with conditions

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, row

I am trying to use LoadingRow for change row colors programatically. It is working as i need. But the problem is with scrollbar. When i use the scrollbar in datagrid my formula is running again and i am getting silly ordered row colors.

here is my code. i am trying to change colors with 17th columns value.

```
        private void dataGrid1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow row = e.Row;
        DataRowView rView = row.Item as DataRowView;
        if (rView != null && rView.Row.ItemArray[17].ToString().Contains("1"))
        {
            renk++;  
        }
        if (renk % 2 == 0)
        {
            e.Row.Background = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF0000"));
        }
        else
        {
            e.Row.Background = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#ffffff"));
        }
    }
```

After running of my code it is working. But when i scrolling down my mouse to see following rows it is working also. Then when i scrolling up mouse to see first rows my code does'nt work good. You can see difference between opened time and after scrolling pictures below.

[image: First order is good] [image: Why it is confusing]

Thanks.

Comment: What is renk, i.e. what is the exact condition under which the rows should be coloured?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work if you turn off virtualization on the `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid
    EnableRowVirtualization="False"
```

It's reusing the `DataGridRow` objects for different rows. If you've got 10,000 rows and 30 are visible, it's silly to create 10,000 `DataGridRow` control objects. If you've got enough items, the above will bring your application to its knees. However, you may have a small number of items, in which case the above kludge is good enough.

But you don't need to do that in any case. The correct way to do it is to leave row virtualization enabled and work with WPF instead of against it, like the XAML below.

I don't know what your column 17 is called so I created a quickie table populated with fizz buzz items. My equivalent of your column 17 is a column named `State`. If you provide a little more information we can make this match what you're actually doing.

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding FizzBuzzTable}"
    >
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Fizz">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="Buzz">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding State}" Value="FizzBuzz">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="GreenYellow" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: it is worked. Also i will try DataGrid.RowStyleSelector as @GCamel's answer.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @enderaric I would not use `RowStyleSelector` here. That's heavy overkill for this case. It can be made to solve this problem, but it'll require a lot more code than writing a single style with some triggers in it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I coded the trigger in XAML like you have in your example and added a property in my binding class, then just set that property as needed.  Worked great.  I especially appreciate that you showed the cheap/easy EnableRowVirtualization first, then talked to a better solution.  If I could give you more points than 1, I would.

Answer (score 0):

can be easier with xaml as Datagrid as property for that

AlternationCount = 2

and the brush AlternatingRowBackground

Comment: AlternationCount can change. it will change with different parameters. I know alternationcount. But i have to control datagrid with column 17th value.

Comment: ok, where did you init renk++;  ?? because if the grid is virtualizing then you will never start from the same position

Comment: did you try to put a converter on AlternatingRowBackground depending on the 17th value converted to color brush

Comment: outside of loadingrow function. i want to run loadingrow event only after populate datagrid. i dont want run the event with scrollbar. my problem is this.

Comment: it is due to virtualization; i am sure you event is fired when you scroll up or ??

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

DataGrid.RowStyleSelector

removing virtualization is not good !

Comment: I will try. Then i will write the result.